# How to plot (x^2+y^2-1)^3=x^2*y^3?

Tags: inkscape

I knew the function plotter,but it seemed no way to plot (x^2+y^2-1)^3=x^2*y^3.
I am new to inkscape, thanks for any answer in advance!

Comment: The function plotter needs a function to plot and what you have is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need exact function or just heart shape? Try to use Parametric Curves Extension with next formulas: X-Function `16*sin(t)**3`, Y-Function: `13*cos(t)-5*cos(2*t)-2*cos(3*t)-cos(4*t)`

Here is result:

[image: Parametric Heart Curve]